# Setup an auto recovery database with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I've 2 dbs, `mainDB` in the same server as NodeJS application, and `backupDB` physically located on another server.
So how can I do to setup Mongoose so that if his loses the connection to `mainDB` the application automatically connect to `backupDB`, and if it becomes available again mongoose must reconnect to `mainDB`

How can I do?

There is a specific option for this?

Thanks in advance